# Javascript Typeahead set JSON properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying putting this to work:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-external-dataset

But I don't seem to write the JSON properly, I have done this way successfuly:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-local-dataset

But not with the JSON format (I have to say that I am new to JSON but have read and tried a couple of ways to carry that out without success.)

So, this is my JSON (countries.json) in the same file as the javascript that calls it.

```
{"countries": [

{'accounts':'Audi', 'accounts':'BMW', 'accounts':'Bugatti', 'accounts':'Ferrari','accounts': 'Ford'}

]}
```

and this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'accounts',
        prefetch: 'countries.json',
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The example that you gave returns just the array of countries. Why do you need a json object instead?

Comment: I want to use json because I want to keep my data on a json file and load it  instead of writing the array on my code

Comment: First, you can have the array, and just the array, in your json file. Add this to a file.json and load it at prefetch: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']

Comment: What you mean prefetch : ['Audi',....] I want prefetch to call the json file, could you explain it a little bit better with the code, in an answer instead of a comment¿? I think I get the idea of what u say, but I don't know exactly because I am noob to this, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the content of your `countries.json` into this, and it will work ok.

```
['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']
```

Seem like the typeahead store some result in the localStorage, you have to clear the localStorage to make sure it works.
[image]

Comment: Tried my JSON like you said, and like this:

{"countries":
['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']

}

With the typeahead function as I said before, but it doesn't autocomplete, what could be wrong¿? Thank you

Comment: No, you should remove the `{"countries"}` and just keep the content in `[]`like my post.

Comment: Yes, I did it, exactly as u said but It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Where do you put your countries.json?

Comment: In the same path as the scripts that calls it is

Comment: Please clear the local storage as I recommend in the answer. Typeahead cache the result inse localStorage so it can't read the new valid json.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but what I mean cleaning the localStorage, localStorage of where¿? how¿?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82684/discussion-between-huy-hoang-pham-and-adon).

Comment: Open the developer tool and clear the local Storage. If you don't know how to open the developer tool for your browser, google it :D.